# UITabBarController is null?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I was trying to create a tab bar based application from scratch but I'm having some issues. Basically I have my AppDelegate.h, AppDelegate.m and a MainView.xib. In the the .h file I have:

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITabBarController *tabBarController;

@end
```

In My .m I have:

```
@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize tabBarController = _tabBarController;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

And in my xib file I have my files owner as a class of Appdelegate and I have my outlet from there hooked up with a Tab Bar Controller. The problem is that my controller is returning null and thus isn't being set as the rootViewController. What step/idea am I missing in setting up my app? Thanks in advance!

EDIT FIXED: Since I was starting from a empty application I didn't have 'Main nib file base name' set, so I just had to set it to the nib I was trying to load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I was starting from a empty application I didn't have 'Main nib file base name' set, so I just had to set it to the nib I was trying to load.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the view controllers that will be accessed through the tabs on your Tab Bar Controller. Then you must assign them to the `viewControllers` property of the Tab Bar. You can do this just before setting the Tab Bar as the window's `rootViewController`:

```
MyViewController1 *vc1 = [[MyViewController1 alloc] init];
MyViewController2 *vc2 = [[MyViewController2 alloc] init];
NSArray *controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:vc1, vc2, nil];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers;
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I already have controllers set up in the XIB file. I tried it the way you suggested but I still get the error "Applications are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch." The view controller I have hooked up with the outlet is null for some reason

Comment: Did you keep the line where you set the Tab Bar Controller as the `rootViewController`? You shouldn't take it off.

Answer (score 0):

Normally the appDelegate object is not a subclass of UIResponder, but a subclass of NSObject.

Are you hooking the TabBar instance to the first responder in your xib file? take into account that this won't work as the first responder is only a proxy object and setting the class type to it won't cause an object to be instantiated.

Instead, create an AppDelegate object in your xib file and hook the TabBar to it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I changed it to NSObject, I then added a object and made it a class of my delegate and added that to my xib file. Hooked up the outlet and yet it still doesn't work.

Comment: Hm, I must be missing a step because I downloaded some sample code that was working fine. I then delete the xib and tried to do it my self and I get the same error